# ruby-on-rails-4 has_many :through, dependent: :destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a has_many, :through relationship which I am creating with check boxes. I would also like to create a further relationship from the many-many model.

My case is; I am creating a test plan which has scenarios. I include the scenarios I want by setting a check box.  This creates the scenario_test record and the related scenario_test_steps. So far, so good.

However, when I clear the check box only the scenario_test record is deleted and the scenario_test_steps are left orphaned.
Can anyone offer a solution? some thoughts? I am going about this all wrong?

```
class Scenario < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :scenario_tests, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :test_plans, through: :scenario_tests
end

class TestPlan < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :scenario_tests, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :scenarios, through: :scenario_tests
end

class ScenarioTest < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :test_plan
  belongs_to :scenario
  has_many :scenario_test_steps, dependent: :destroy
end

class ScenarioTestStep < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :scenario_test
end

class TestPlansController < ApplicationController
  def test_plan_params
    params.require(:test_plan).permit(:scenario_ids => [])
  end
end
```

In my view.haml.html

```
= hidden_field_tag "test_plan[scenario_ids][]", nil
%table
  %thead
    %tr
      %th Selected
      %th Scenario Code
      %th Scenario
  %tbody
    - @scenarios.each do |scenario|
      %tr
        %td= check_box_tag "test_plan[scenario_ids][]", scenario.id, @test_plan.scenario_ids.include?(scenario.id), id: dom_id(scenario)
        %td= label_tag dom_id(scenario), scenario.code
        %td= label_tag dom_id(scenario), scenario.name
```

Comment: are you deleting the record with delete or destroy?

Comment: Using check boxes so setting test_plan.scenario_ids = []

Comment: please share the code where you are actually deleting the scenario_test

Comment: I added code from my controller and view, thanks

Comment: what im seeing is you are not destroy anything. callbacks are triggered when you call this `.destroy` on the object. it will destroy its dependants as well. you are just setting scenario_ids to nil

Comment: Right, it is deleting the scenario_test record though.  Does this method call a .delete rather than a .destroy?

Comment: yes try using `.destroy` rather than `.delete` destroy triggers callback while delete just delete that record.

Comment: This is a generated method though, is there some way to influence this or do I need to rethink the design?  Can it be done by clearing a check box?

Comment: `.destroy` is default ruby on rails action and it can be called on any object. try this in `rails console`. i would suggest you to try the flow in rails console by destroy the object manually and see if its dependants are deleted are not as well. and based on that try some design